# TimescaleDB: SELECT COUNT(*) slow on hypertable

Tags: timescaledb

I have a hyper table for exchange candle data set up using TimescaleDB.

- TimescaleDB official image `timescale/timescaledb:latest-pg12` set up and running with Docker with the exact version string `starting PostgreSQL 12.6 on x86_64-pc-linux-musl, compiled by gcc (Alpine 10.2.1_pre1) 10.2.1 20201203, 64-bit`
- Python 3 client
- The table has 5 continuous aggregate views [set up like here](https://docs.timescale.com/latest/using-timescaledb/continuous-aggregates) and around 15 colums

Running the following query is slow (count query generated with SQLAlchemy):

```
SELECT count(*) AS count_1
FROM (SELECT my_hypertable.timestamp AS my_hypertable_timestamp
FROM my_hypertable) AS anon_1
```

Getting a count for a hypertable with 14,000 rows takes 7 seconds on a beefy server, measured from Python script. Whereas for a normal table the query time seems to be sub 10 ms. This makes the `COUNT(*)` on hypertable unusable in most of the situations.

- Is there something in TimescaleDB architecture that makes `COUNT(*)` especially slow?
- If there is something wrong with my set-up, any pointers or guesses what it could be or how to diagnose this further
- If the count() is going to be super slow for architectural reasons, what are the recommendations to work around this - or should it be avoided altogether?

Comment: https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/postgresql-count-made-fast/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can try the approximate_row_count() function (https://docs.timescale.com/api/latest/analytics/approximate_row_count/) which gives an immediate result.

Comment: Thank you so much Benoit! Is there any particular reason why the normal `COUNT` is slow, so I could understand the hypertable limitations better?